# How to effectively stay in-sync when using dfuse streaming API

Tags: blockchain, eos

I'm using dfuse streaming API to built a EOS based application. 
I want to keep an in-sync view of all the data flowing through my smart contract.

I want to ensure that I will always be in sync so I never miss a single block. Using the dfuse streaming API, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `with_progress` feature of the Websocket API, you will receive one `progress` message after each block was processed.

For a given stream (corresponding to a request and an associated `req_id`), when you received a `progress` for a block, you are guaranteed to have seen all the contents it contained in your query (the actions for `get_action_traces`, or the rows for `get_table_rows`).

If you keep track of that `block_num` and/or `block_id`, upon disconnection/reconnections, you can provide it back in your request, and be guaranteed never to miss a beat, even if that means you're reprocessing 1M blocks.

As of November 22nd 2018, the `get_table_rows` request will stream `table_delta` messages that include an `"undo"`/`"redo"` `step`. This allows your app to navigate forks and ensure absolute sync of your application with the longest chain's state.

Check the docs at https://docs.dfuse.io/ and search for `with_progress` for more details.